# How do you enable emmet for nextjs ( js file)?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, emmet

How do you enable emmet for nextjs ( js file)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Emmets don't work in JS files. However, you can set it so that VS Code thinks that it's a JSX file and it would give React IntelliSense.

1. Click the button written "JavaScript" in the Status Bar, which should be at the bottom.

[image]

2. Type "React" and select `react (javascriptreact)`.

[image]

3. After that, the file is set as a React file, and therefore, you can now use Emmets.

[image]

---

If you want all of your JS files to be set as React files, create `.vscode/settings.json` and paste this:

```json
{
  "files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file extension from '.js' to '.jsx'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).